# Agregar datos de un DataGridView a otro desde otra formulario

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Estoy realizando una aplicación que me permita realizar el préstamo de varios equipos o herramientas, entonces, tengo creada un formulario préstamo que registra al usuario y otro formulario que busca el producto en cuestión. Los datos que me gustaría enviar serían el id del producto que se encuentra oculto, el nombre del producto y la cantidad disponible.

Los formularios sería los siguientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde obtengo los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que sería donde los recibiria.

Para recuperar los datos de la base de datos uso el siguiente código.

```
public DataTable Buscar()
{
    string ComandoSQL = "SELECT producto.id_prod, producto.nomb_prod, producto.precio_producto, producto.cantidad, producto.descripcion_prod, producto.id_categoria, categoria.nomb_categoria, producto.id_marca, marca.nomb_marca FROM producto, marca, categoria WHERE producto.id_categoria = categoria.id_categoria AND producto.id_marca = marca.id_marca";
    return MiConexion.EjecutarSentencia(ComandoSQL);
}
```

Y para recuperar los datos del GridView uso el siguiente.

```
private void RecuperarDatos(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    int fila = e.RowIndex;
    id_producto = dtg_Busqueda.Rows[fila].Cells["id_producto"].Value.ToString();
    nombre = dtg_Busqueda.Rows[fila].Cells["nomb_producto"].Value.ToString();
    cantidad = dtg_Busqueda.Rows[fila].Cells["cantidad"].Value.ToString();

    //enviar ok para que ventana padre pueda recibir
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Dispose();
}
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo pongo los datos recuperados en un nuevo GridView en otro formulario?

Comment: Si pudieras poner codigo en lugar de imagenes estaria mucho mejor, gracias

Comment: edita tu pregunta y agrega la informacion, no aqui en los comentarios por que no se puede ni leer bien

Comment: ok y lo que quieres es que se pase que a donde, explica mas tu pregunta y asi puedo ayudarte mejor

Comment: En si solo quieres pasar la misma informacion no editaras nada??

Comment: Lo único que necesito es pasar información para poder realizar detalles de préstamos de productos.

Comment: Los formularios son clases, las clases pueden tener métodos que reciben parámetros, o pueden tener propiedades con sus getters/setters. ¿El nuevo formulario ya tiene el grid creado?

Comment: Los griedview  ya están creados, eso son las imagenes que están en la pregunta, disculpa si no conteste antes, pero tuve que ocuparme de unos asuntos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo un articulo donce explico justamente sobre este tema

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

la idea es que crees una interfaz para desacoplar la comunicacion entre los forms y puedas invocar un metodo en el form padres, pasando datos desde el form hijo (en este caso el form de busqueda)

NUNCA accedas directo a los controles de la instancia del form padre porque generas acoplamiento, invoca un metodo definido en la interfaz enviando los datos del producto seleccionado, como explico en el articulo.

La idea es que definas una interfaz como ser

```
interface IForm{
   void Metodo1(int idproducto);
}
```

Entonces haces que el form padre implemente la interface

```
public class FormPrincipal : Form, IForm {
    //codigo del form

    //implementas el metodo de la interfaz que recibe el producto
}
```

Cuando invocas el form pasa la instancia en el constructor

```
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmBuscar obj = new frmBuscar(this);
    obj.Show();      
}
```

En el formbuscar usarias

```
 public class frmBuscar : Form{

     private IForm _form;

     public frmBuscar(IForm form){ //este es el constructor
          _form = form;
     }

     //para acceder al form principal lo haces por medio de _form
     //donde llamarias al metodo de la interfaz
 }
```